# Blank row in XML after writeXML

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I'm using this to save my data from dataGridViewX1 to an XML file.

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("itemstable"); 

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewX1.ColumnCount; i++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(dataGridViewX1.Columns[i].Name, typeof(System.String));
                }

                DataRow myrow;
                int icols = dataGridViewX1.Columns.Count;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow drow in this.dataGridViewX1.Rows)
                {
                    myrow = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= icols - 1; i++)
                    {

                        myrow[i] = drow.Cells[i].Value;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(myrow);
                }

                dt.WriteXml("items.xml");
```

This is what the XML will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <itemstable>
    <Datum>18.02.2014</Datum>
    <a>45</a>
    <b>12</b>   
  </itemstable>
  <itemstable />
</DocumentElement>
```

How can I get rid of  `<itemstable />` when creating the XML, because it occurs a blank row after reading the XML back into dataGridViewX1?

Answer (score 0):

Off-by one error:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= icols - 1; i++)
                   ^^--- should be just "<"
```

If `count` comes back as `5`, for instance, you'll be doing

```
0,1,2,3,4,5 - 6 elements
```

instead of

```
0,1,2,3,4 - 5 elements
```

Comment: its still doing the same